# how to 'properly' write tests in typescript

Tags: typescript, tdd, jestjs

i really love tdd, and want to pick up a new language, and have chosen typescript. Unfortunately i'm struggling to write tests the way i want to.

say i am testing the following class:

```
class Container {

    private numbers: number[];

    constructor(){
            this.numbers = [];
    }

    addNumber(numberToAdd: number) : void {
        //implementation
    }

    removeNumber(numberToRemove: number) : void {
        //implementation
    }

    getNumbers(): number[] {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

my instinct is to do something like this:

```
describe( "container", () => {
    let sut: Container;
    beforeEach(() => sut = new Container());

    describe( "add number", () => {
        let number1 = 1;
        let numbers = sut.getNumbers();

        test( "number should be added", () => {
             numbers.should.contain(number1);
        });  

        test("exactly one number should have been added", () => {
             numbers.length.should.be(0);
        });     
    });

    describe( "remove number", () => {
        let addedNumber = 2;
        sut.addNumber(addedNumber);
        sut.removeNumber(addedNumber);
        let numbers = sut.getNumbers();

        test( "added number should be removed", () => {
            numbers.length.should.be(0);
        });
    });
});
```

jest won't execute this properly. the Container is not instantiated before every test statement - i'm not sure why not, maybe it doesn't like my nested describe statements? obviously i could instantiate the sut in each describe separately, but i'd be repeating code...

how do you write tests in typescript? do you have any tips? if you could share your best practices that would be great. maybe jest isn't the right tool for this job?

i was also wondering if anybody would like to share a link an open source project which is a really good example of how to test in typescript

Comment: You're using `sut` **outside** of the tests.

Comment: Sut (subject under test) is the thing I am testing in this file, so surely it makes sense to expose it to all tests in this file? Please could you explain why what I did is bad? To me it does not make sense to new up the class in each test - seems like repeated code to me

Comment: Using it in all tests is fine. What is nit fine is to use it **outside** of the tests. You can use it inside the callbacks passed to test(), because those are tests. You can't use it inside the callbacks passed to describe(), because those aren't tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is actually about `jest`, not about TypeScript.

What happens is the statements within the nested `describe()` calls are executed before the `beforeEach()` is called. Thus you get undefined.

```
describe( "container", () => {
    let sut: Container;
    beforeEach(() => sut = new Container());

    describe( "add number", () => {
        let number1 = 1;
        let numbers = sut.getNumbers();
    });

    describe( "remove number", () => {
        let addedNumber = 2;
        sut.addNumber(addedNumber);
        sut.removeNumber(addedNumber);
        let numbers = sut.getNumbers();
    });
});
```

As mentioned by @JB Nizet, you should move these statements with tests, or within their own `beforeEach()` calls.

IMO, I tend to avoid `beforeAll()` and `beforeEach()`. It makes the test more magical and harder to understand.

I would suggest to create your own setup/teardown method and call them within the test. e.g.:

```
function setup() {
  return new Container();
}

describe( "container", () => {
    describe( "remove number", () => {
        test( "added number should be removed", () => {
            const sut = setup()

            sut.addNumber(2);
            sut.removeNumber(2);
            const actual = sut.getNumbers();

            actual.length.should.be(0);
        });
    });
});
```